# Were wristlocks ever part of Judo randori?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, judo, sport, joint-lock

The [Kodokan goshin-jutsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodokan_Goshin_Jutsu) kata as well as several 20th century judo texts<sup>1</sup> demonstrate various wristlocks as a self defence technique, similar to the teaching of atemi. However since at least [1900](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/9401/8910), they appear to have been barred from use in randori or competition.<sup>2</sup>

**Were wristlocks ever permitted before this?**

Since BJJ notably allows wristlocks as submissions, I had assumed that they were permitted in early judo.

---

---

1. > [image]
   >   <sup>• [*My Method Of Self-Defence*](http://www.judokai.net/Documents/My_Method_of_Self_Defense%20-%20Kawaishi.pdf), Mikinosuke Kawaishi</sup>
2. > <sup>Even those above *shodan* rank are not permitted to perform the *kwansetsuwaza* on a finger-joint or wrist, while playing the *randori* contest.</sup>
   >   <sup>• [*Judo: Japanese Physical Culture*](https://judoinfo.com/rules3/), Sumitomo Arima (1908)</sup>

Comment: Not quite reliable, but the comments at this link says Judo forbid wrist locks since 1899, with the formation of the first set of competition rules: https://www.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/7iqb20/were_wristlocks_ever_a_part_of_judo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syd Hoare (8th Dan) in a lecture given to the EJU Foundation Degree Course at Bath University in Aug 2005 said the following with respect to his research on the inclusion of wrist locks in early judo:

> Let us now look at the new 13 Article Butokukai Jujitsu Competition Rules which
>   were completed in **1899**:
>
> ...
>
> 2. The *nage-waza* included sutemiwaza (sacrifice throws) as happens today and
>      the katamewaza included strangles, joint-locks and hold-downs. **However the
>      allowed locks must have included all sorts of locks such as leg-locks and wrist
>      locks** and shoulder locks. Note that osae-waza (restraints/hold-downs) were
>      not defined.
>
>    ...
> 3. Finger, toe and ankle locks were not allowed probably because they were seen
>      as prone to injury but knee, shoulder, **wrist, neck and spine locks were not
>      specifically banned.** Knee locks occurred in competition in the very early
>      Kodokan days so perhaps these other locks were allowed as well.
>
> ...
>
> #### Kodokan Competition and Randori Rules
>
> Within one year of the formulation of the Butokukai competition rules the Kodokan
>   produced its own rules (Kodokan Judo Randori Shobu Shimpan-ho) in **1900**. Note
>   that these were randori and competition rules. They were identical to the Butokukai
>   ones but with three small changes which were... the (3rd) difference was in article 13 which was changed to read, **“Even 1st Dan and above are not allowed to use toe and finger locks or ankle and wrist locks.” Maybe the wrist-lock inclusion here was because of a typo/omission in the earlier Butokukai rules.**
>
> - [*Development Of Judo Competition Rules*](http://www.judo-snijders.nl/download-judo/Development%20of%20competition%20rules.html), Syd Hoare (2005)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays only Elbowlock is **officially** permitted in judo competitions.
Nevertheless, National federation (french judo federation in particular) has set up for 5 years Newaza competitions where ankle-knee-shoulder-wristlock are authorized.
You could remark that sometimes udegarami turns out to be shoulderlock even in international slam.

But let's come back to wristlock and modern judo. Actualy, when tori in competion (even Paris or Duseledorf) try to do jujigatame, he practices a hidden wristlock to free uke's hand from his judogi. That's the reason why Judo french team trains to avoid wristlock by leaving no room between the harm and chest when defending jujigatame. I talk about hidden wristlock because if you practice with your right handle a wristlock on the right wrist of your oponent, you can hide this bad gesture (from the eyes of referee) thanks to your left handle.