# Are Biceps Slicers legal in judo?

Tags: judo, history, sport, joint-lock

There are a number of [compression locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_lock) in grappling, which function with tori placing a limb (acting as a fulcrum) in the crook of one of uke's joints, and applying pressure to flex the joint over the limb, simultaneously crushing the muscles/ligaments either side of it and hyper-flexing the joint around it. While

- Achilles Locks ([*ashi-hishigi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashi-Hishigi), targetting the ankle joint)
- Calf/Thigh Slicers ([*hiza-hishigi*](https://judoinfo.com/leglocks/) etc, targeting the knee joint)
- and even Neck Locks ([*kubi-hishigi*](https://judoinfo.com/kubiwaza/) etc)

are historic judo techniques (if banned in randori/competition for over a century), I have never seen the Biceps Slicer described as an explicit technique in any Kodokan material.<sup>1 2</sup>

[image]

**Is a biceps slicer a legal technique** (since it is a joint lock targeting the elbow), **and if not, was it ever taught in judo?**

---

1. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvLKfeSeOpw) it is being demonstrated in a Kosen Judo club however, using pressure from a leg triangle to apply the lock.
2. [Here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9E0z5fJGuWk) being demonstrated by John Anderson (Kodokan 8th Dan), using pressure from the other arm.

Comment: The person who taught this armlock to me studied with John Anderson (RIP); this is what I learned. I'm amazed by what you can find on YouTube these days.

Answer (score 4):

I was taught a compression armlock by a US national referee. I am not formally familiar with the term bicep slicer, but your description of the armlock matches exactly what I learned.

It's a joint lock on the elbow that can be performed in a controlled manner, so there is nothing to make it illegal. It's legal.

I don't recall whether I have seen this armlock in judo publications.

The compression armlock is not one of my competition techniques, so I have never  tested whether it is allowed in competition. I personally find it only works roughly half the time, mostly based on the partner.

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends on the rule set your training is targeting; but with that being said...the bicep slicer is legal accoring to the current IJF, and Free-Style Judo competition rule-sets.